# How do I get IntelliJ to see my remote git branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using BitBucket and I created a branch on another machine with IntelliJ and pushed it in to my repo. I can see the branch on the BitBucket site, but when I try to access the remote branch using IntelliJ on another machine I can't see the new branch when I go to `VCS -> git -> Remote Branches`. I tried doing a pull, but that only brought down the head changes (which currently points to master), and didn't update the remote branches list. Is there something you have to do to see the remote branches (besides Head and Master) in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

In case anyone runs in to something similar I found that on my IntelliJ at least I had to run a **fetch** and then I could see the remote branches. It didn't appear that a pull was sufficient even though pull is supposed to fetch.

Comment: pull is not sufficient because it can only pull from the known branches

Comment: From the IntelliJ terminal, neither `git fetch` nor `git fetch --verbose` provide me with the remote branches that I know exist.  Similarly `git branch --all` does not display my additional remote branches.  I started this project by opening a folder which already contained a git repo, and in that folder on disk I've already fetched and checked out a feature branch that I want to update.

Comment: I didn't use the terminal, I clicked "VCS" ->  "Git" -> "Fetch" and it worked.

Comment: I tried performing fetch through IntelliJ itself but the other remote branch didn't appear. I had to restart IntelliJ and now it appears.

Answer (score 6):

I found the same thing with IntelliJ, also fetch not only gets all remote branches for the current repository in your project, but it also gets them for all repositories in the project.

It is safe to say that a pull only fetches for the current repository and branch that you are on, and fetch fetches for all repositories in the project.

(I would have simply commented on Zipper's excellent answer, but I seem to only have one reputation point :-()

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same case, my repo is in Bitbucket, I created a branch from another machine but in my main machine I was unable to see it. I tried several times `VCS->Git->Fetch` without success. I even restart IntelliJ but same result. 
To solve my issue, I created the branch manually and use:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/my-branch my-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone came here for this issue in PyCharm (by same creators), I added new branches after I had already cloned the repo into PyCharm. Fetch, from either the command line or within the GUI, would not pickup the new branches even after I tried several times and restarted the program.

I ended up deleting the repo, re-cloning, and was then able to find and checkout the branches I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per posting below "VCS > Git > Fetch" command

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206598135-How-can-I-refresh-remote-Git-branches-